# Default Terminal In VS Code Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have had a setup for a while to run C++ programs in VS Code. It was basically a tasks.json which looked like this

```
"tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Compile and run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "",
        "args": [
          "g++",
          "${fileBasename}",
          "-o",
          "test",
          "&&",
           ...
   }
```

I had also kept a settings.json to define the terminal to be used which was command Prompt,
For some reason in the latest update for VS Code my setup got messed and it does not work anymore.

I would like to know the right syntax to define `cmd` as the terminal for running the tasks since things like `&&` `<` `>` dont work in powershell

Comment: I do know nothing about `tasks` in Visual Code, but `&&` seems to work, see: [How do I run multiple commands on one line in PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/questions/612409/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-on-one-line-in-powershell) and `< and >` also work in powershell.

Comment: when I say `< and >` I mean they dont work for input output redirection, `g++ ECODOWN.cpp -o test ; test < input.txt > output.txt;` here is a cmd for refernce

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243949/how-to-use-stdin-stdout-redirect-in-visual-studio-code-task

Comment: @Luuk Yes this also worked

Answer (score 0):

After [Luuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724039/luuk)'s comment I did more digging and found the followig to work for my vs code tasks problem. I only had to change `&&` to `;` and for the input out redirection I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16548699/15619236). Now my tasks.json looks like this

```
 "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Compile and run",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "",
        "args": [
          "g++",
          "${fileBasename}",
          "-o",
          "test",
          ";",
          "cmd",
          "/c",
          "'test.exe < input.txt > output.txt'",
          ";",
          "del",
          "*exe",
          ";",
          "del",
          "${fileBasename}"
        }
]
```